# TBXML not parsing TBXMLElement text, while child element tags also present in existing parent tag?

Tags: objective-c, xml-parsing, tbxml

My XML is like this:

```
<office>
   <item>
    NOIDA OFFICE:
    <OfficeAddress>B-20, SECTOR 57 NOIDA (U.P) 201301</OfficeAddress>
   </item>
</office>
```

And I am trying to parse with TBXML parser.

Here my problem is, `OfficeAddress` value is accessible as a child element of `item` but `text of <item>  NOIDA OFFICE:` is not getting parsed.

Its showing me `text of <item> is NULL` and showing only one child element `<OfficeAddress>` with associated text.

I want to parse `NOIDA OFFICE: as item name`. Anyone please help me, Advance appreciate on your help.

Happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not able parse your XML. Please change the xml in server side like this.

```
<Office>
<item name=NOIDA OFFICE>
<OfficeAddress>B-20, SECTOR 57 NOIDA (U.P) 201301</OfficeAddress>
</item>
</Office>
```

Comment: I don't want to change existing xml, as it will affecting on some of  other web apps parsing.  Do you know will it work with NSXml parser?